# Why can I not concatenate a const(char)* to a string in D?

Tags: string, concatenation, d

The code

```
string bar = "Hello ";
const(char) * foo = "world!";
bar ~= foo;
```

fails to compile in the third line. Why? What elegant alternatives do I have?

The error output is `Error: cannot append type const(char)* to type string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use a `const(char)*`?

```
string bar = "Hello ";
string foo = "world!";
bar ~= foo;
```

String literals in D are of type `string`, you shouldn't ever need to use a `const(char)*`, except when interfacing with C code.

The reason D doesn't allow that concatenation is because `const(char)*` isn't a string, in any sense of the word. Strings in D are `immutable(char)[]` (which is `alias`'d by `string`). A `const(char)*` is just a pointer to a constant character. Unlike C and C++, there is no implied null-terminator, so D can't and won't assume there is one.

If for whatever reason you absolutely must use a `const(char)*` and you *know* that it is null terminated, then you can make a `const(char)[]` out of it by slicing, which you can then append to a `string`:

```
string bar = "Hello ";
const(char)* foo = "world!";
bar ~= foo[0..strlen(foo)];
```

Comment: Slicing `foo` doesn't give you a `string`, but `const(char)[]`. It's still compatible for concatenation with `string bar`, but you would get an error if you attempted to store the result of slicing `foo` in a `string` variable.

Comment: @jA_cOp: Well spotted, I'll fix it.

Comment: Is the string then null-terminated in memory, or should I write bar ~= foo[0..strlen(foo)+1]; in the last line for C interop?

Comment: BTW, I had to use a const(char)* in my code, because it was a function parameter which came from C interop.

Comment: @ralph: A `string` isn't guaranteed to be null-terminated, and you shouldn't add the null-terminator on the end otherwise that will increase the `string.length`. When passing to C functions, use `toStringz(myString)`.

Answer (score 4):

`string` is an alias for `immutable(char)[]`, i.e., a mutable slice of immutable characters. `bar` in your code is an array slice of this type.

The relationship between `const(char)*` and string literals in D is just that string literals are always null terminated, and typed as either `immutable(char)[]` (i.e. `string`), or `immutable(char)*` for convenient interoperability with C code; the latter being implicitly convertible to `const(char)*`. It's important to note that this is only the case for *string literals*: arrays are not necessarily null terminated in the general case, and they are **not** implicitly convertible to their pointer equivalent (though the member `.ptr` of any slice `T[]` is of type `T*` and points to the first element of the slice).

The concatenation operators work with arrays as well as user-defined types with the relevant operator overloads, and nothing else. As D does not allow overloading of operators for inbuilt types, it's not possible to make them work with pointers.

The solution is to make a slice of the string the pointer points to, by using the slice operator which works on arrays and pointers alike:

```
import core.stdc.string : strlen;

string bar = "Hello ";
const(char)* foo = "world!";
bar ~= foo[0 .. strlen(foo)];
```

In the above, the expression `foo[0 .. strlen(foo)]` is of type `const(char)[]`, which can be concatenated with `bar`, which is of type `immutable(char)[]` (i.e. `string`).